# Resource routing (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm mainly a php developer and taking my first steps into Laravel. I have a specific question about a situation in a tutorial I'm watching.

The topic of the tutorial is Eloquent in combination with resource (controller).

The route defined in web.php is

```
Route::resource('photos', PhotoController::class);
```

So 127.0.0.1:8000/photos should route to the index method in the PhotoController, right?

In the tutorial however the url 127.0.0.1:8000 is typed into the browser and routes to the index method in the PhotoController. I don't quit get why. Why is it not nescesairy to add /photos in the address?

Comment: they could be doing a redirect, but otherwise wouldn't be able to tell you

Comment: Please add Route('/','Controller@index')->name('index');
you need to provide  landing route